# join two different tables and remove duplicated entries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm complete novice in sql queries. I have two tables:

**table1:**

```
id_s  name   post_code     city     subject
------------------------------------------
1     name1  postal1    city1    subject1
2     name2  postal2    city2    subject2
3     name3  postal3    city3    subject3
4     name4  postal4    city4    subject4
...
~350
```

**table2:**

```
id_p  name   post_code     city     subject
------------------------------------------
1     name1  postal1    city1    subject1
2     name2  postal2    city2    subject2
3     name3  postal3    city3    subject3
4     name4  postal4    city4    subject4 
...
~1200
```

I want to join both tables, and remove entries with same name and postal code. I found some answers on how to do it but they were too complicated.

Comment: i think you want `UNION`. what is your desired output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `UNION` clause, `UNION` will check for duplicates and only distinct rows will be returned

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

Edit: To store data from both table without duplicates, do this

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 X 
                  WHERE A.NAME = X.NAME AND 
                  A.post_code = x.post_code)
```

This will insert rows from table2 that do not match name, postal code from table1

Alternative is that You can also create new table and not touch table1 and table2

```
CREATE TABLE TABLENAME AS
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

Comment: Thanks. btw. It will work when tables got different number of columns ?

Comment: Ok. Before I will use it, I need to know if it will destroy the table 2 and table 1 will become one big mixed table ?

Comment: This will return only data and will not change anything in underlying tables. Do you want to delete rows directly in table?

Comment: @chris when you give a `SELECT` command you are only reading from your tables, nothing gets destroyed.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to write it. My output would be to create one big table, and it's not important if I would delete any table or leave them

Comment: @rs. Maybe `CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS SELECT ...` would be better?

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko, yes it is, i was not sure if OP wanted new table or not.

Comment: @rs. I is always safer to create a new table, then to change existing. BTW, a simple `VIEW` could solve this problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a `SELECT INTO`  command like this

```
SELECT * INTO newtable FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2;
```

This will create a newtable from both table1 and table2 without any duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple one:

```
(select * from table1 MINUS select * from table2)
UNION
(select * from table2 MINUS select * from table1)
```