# SQL join tables but exclude duplicates where all columns match except 1

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates, union

I have little experience with SQL and need to join tables with many duplicate entries.
I have browsed for an answer quite a bit and the closest I could find to my problem was this:

[join two different tables and remove duplicated entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303573/join-two-different-tables-and-remove-duplicated-entries)

It suggested this code, to match the tables by their name and postcode columns.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 X 
                  WHERE A.NAME = X.NAME AND 
                  A.post_code = x.post_code)
```

My only problem is that I have dozens of columns and dont want to write them all out.
Basically, I need to delete duplicates where ALL columns are the same, EXCEPT the datetime column.

(the duplicates where entered at differnt times, so even if the value in the datetime column is different, for me this is still a duplicate.)

Is there are way to join the tables but deleting duplicates where all but 1 column match?

Update:

Thank you so much for the answer! I probably did this wrong, but now I am getting SQL error because there are too many columns:

create unique index unq_audi_all_columns on audi_all ( `Vehicle`, `listed Price`, `Anunciante`, `Marca`, `Modelo`, `Série`, `Versão`, `Combustível`, `Mês de Registo`, `Ano de Registo`, `Quilómetros`, `Cilindrada`, `Potência`, `Valor Fixo`, `Aceita retoma`, `Possibilidade de financiamento`, `Segmento`, `Cor`, `Tipo de Caixa`, `Número de Mudanças`, `Nº de portas`, `Lotação`, `Classe do veículo`, `Tracção`, `Garantia de Stand (incl. no preço)`, `Registo(s)`, `Livro de Revisões completo`, `Não fumador`, `2º Chave`, `Jantes de Liga Leve`, `Ar Condicionado`, `Condição`, `Inspecção válida até`, `Origem`, `Estofos`, `Numero de Airbags` , `Metalizado` ,`Garantia mecanica fabricante até`, `Filtro de Particulas`, `Tecto de Abrir`, `Medida Jantes de Liga Leve`, `VIN`, `IVA dedutível`, `Emissões CO2`, `IUC`, `ou até`, `Matrícula`, `Consumo Combinado`, `Autonomia Máxima`, `Consumo Urbano`, `Consumo Extra Urbano`, `Capota`, `Capota Eléctrica`, `Clássico`, `Salvado`, `Valor sem IUC`, `Valor sem ISV`, [...]

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1070 - Too many key parts specified; max 32 parts allowed

Comment: Most people here want sample data _and_ expected result as formatted text. (No images, no links.)

Comment: @jarlh 'most' might be an exaggeration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevent duplicates by creating a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_table1_all_columns on table1 ( . . . );  -- you gotta list the columns here.
```

You do need to list the columns, but that is necessary so the database knows your intention.  It is easy to construct the list, with something like:

```
select group_concat(column_name, ', ')
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'table1';
```

Then your insert will return an error if there are duplicates.  Or to avoid them, use `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into table1 
    select *
    from table2
    on duplicate key update name = values(name);  -- this does nothing but it avoids an error on a duplicated row
```