# Join 2 tables in SQL without duplicates

Tags: sql, inner-join

wonder if someone could help, I want to join 2 tables with many to many relationship:

Table 1
cart_id, city, date, sku, qty

Table 2
customer_id, city, date, sku, qty

I would like to join both tables, however at the sku level with inner-join all works fine, when I add sku to my view; however, if I want to return sum(qty) by city for example, then the numbers gets duplicated, any help on how I can join without duplicates please??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [join two different tables and remove duplicated entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303573/join-two-different-tables-and-remove-duplicated-entries)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data and desired results.