# Copy data from one table to another without creating duplicate records SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, copy

I am trying to create a job that copies new data from one table into another and thinking of creating a stored procedure. Even with only using the simple copy method, it creates duplicate records.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table2
```

Would there anything that could possibly be defined to prevent duplicates to be created maybe within the stored procedure or anywhere else?

What I can only think of is to wipe clean the Table1 before the INSERT command is executed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303573/join-two-different-tables-and-remove-duplicated-entries

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Thank you @NickGr, that should do it.

Comment: @jarlh It would be RDBMS.

Comment: Which one? There are dozens of them. (DB2, Oracle, SQL Server etc.)

Comment: @jarlh SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique field on Table1 then you can join Table1 to Table2 using this field. For example:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (id, Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT id, Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table2
left join Table1 on Table1.id = Table2.id 
where Table1.id is null;
```

If you have no unique field, then you can use this SQL script:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table2
left join Table1 on Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1 and Table1.Column2 = Table2.Column2 and Table1.Column3 = Table2.Column3 
where Table1.Column1 is null;
```

This select will return only records that exist in `Table2` but do not exist in `Table1`